# How to check if user's logged in, in react native using firebase?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Here's what I have so far, I use redux to maintain the login state globally. In my login screen, I'm using action creator to log user in like so...

```
    // In LoginScreen file
    onLogin = () => {
      this.props.accountLogin({ email, password });
    }
```

And in actions file, `accountLogin` is defined as:

```
    // In auth_action file
    export const accountLogin = ({ email, password }) => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(user => {
          dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user })});
      });
    };
```

Then, in reducer file, case `LOGIN_SUCCESS` is handled like so...

```
    // In auth_reducer file
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      // ... Other stuff
      user: null
    };
    export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
      // ... Other cases
      // Login Successful case
      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, user: action.payload };
        // After this return statement, I now have user's profile info
    };
```

So my question is, how do I persist user's profile info so that next time user opens the app, they don't have to re-login? I've done some research, and this is what I have:

```
    // Use autoRehydrate and persistStore in 'redux-persist'
    // In store file
    import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import { autoRehydrate, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
    import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
    import reducers from '../reducers';

    const store = createStore(
      reducers,
      {},
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        autoRehydrate()
      )
    );

    persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage, whitelist: ['auth'] });

    export default store;
```

And of course, I did handle `REHYDRATE` case in my `auth_reducer` file. But still, it's true that after user reopens the app, I have the user info from last time that user used the app, how can I use this piece of information to continue modify my data in firebase database?

For example, if user reopens the app, and wishes to change his name, how does firebase know this is an authorized user? How to write this `changeName` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method helps you with that. Set this in your componentWillMount

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('user logged')
      }
   });
```

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: Thank you @soutot ,   is that like a listener? So whenever I exit the app, auth state will change? Then what would happen when I reopen the app? Automatically log me in?

Comment: Yes, Firebase stores locally the auth user. Besides of logging out, uninstalling or cleaning app data, whenever you open the app it will recognize you as an auth user.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question though: When I go to user's home page, where user's name will be displayed in the header, this means that I'll have to get user's info in `componentWillMount()` method, do I call `const {currentUser} = firebase.auth()` to get the currently logged in user's info? If so, then I wouldn't need to use redux-persist to persist user's data right?

Comment: Yes. Username will always be available for you in firebase data while it is logged. Here's more info about it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users
However, sometimes you need to store more info, then I would recommend you to have the user in your database and get the data from there. Managing data from the storage is easier than the authentication.

Comment: Hey @soutot I put this in a splash screen and if the user logged i navigate hem to Home screen, and its work fine **But** when I create user used createUserWithEmailAndPassword() in then() statement i want to navigate the user to a confirmation screen but it does not navigate me, it navigate to Home directly How can i handle it?